# Render Error on Main Site

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I noticed this (Chrome 26, Windows 7) on the main site of Web Applications:

[image: info image on sprite too close]

[image: sprite]

As seen above the info image is too close to the unanswered image on the sprite

rev 2013.4.8.61

- Firefox 19.0.2 - Windows 7
- Google Chrome 26.0.1410.43 - MacOSX 10.7.5
- Safari 6.0.3 (7536.28.10) - MacOSX 10.7.5

Comment: I'm seeing it too. Firefox 19.0.2 on Windows 7.

Comment: On my chrome for android beta, it isn't there anymore.

Comment: I'm not seeing it either, nor did I see it on any other sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be resolved now with the correct spacing (unless an employee corrects me)

[image: Correct spacing]